# Excel VBA formula Referencing between sheets

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I am trying to add below code to my macro like to link the formula to an other sheet `&INDEX(Sheet1!AA$3:Sheet1!AA$18;` but somehow this is not working.

```
.Cells(intFirstEmptyCell, 1).FormulaLocal = "=""ORD-""&INDEX(Sheet1!AA$3:Sheet1!AA$18;MATCH(Q" & intFirstEmptyCell & ";Sheet1!AB$3:Sheet1!AB$18;0))&TEXT(COUNTIF(Q$3:Q" & intFirstEmptyCell & ";Q" & intFirstEmptyCell & ");""0000"")"
```

Comment: Use the macro recorder. It will solve your ills. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Sheet1!AA$3:Sheet1!AA$18
Sheet1!AB$3:Sheet1!AB$18
```

... to,

```
Sheet1!AA$3:AA$18
Sheet1!AB$3:AB$18
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but still not working. Formula in spreadsheet looks like this and is not linked to the sheet1 ="ORD-"&INDEX(Sheet1!AA$3:AA$18;MATCH(Q8;Sheet1!AB$3:AB$18;0))&TEXT(COUNTIF(Q$3:Q8;Q8);"0000")

Comment: problem fixed had to change form Sheet1! into Sheet name.

Comment: Glad you got sorted out. Unfortunately I can only offer solutions in the form they are proposed.